# Detecting one single edge in a image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to detect the location of an approximately horizontal edge in my image.

Initially, I tried to accomplish this by just taking the column-wise maximum, but this turned out to be rather noisy and naive since the horizontally neighboring pixels are not taken into account.

```
y_edge = img.argmax(axis=1)
```

For example:

[image: column-wise maximum]

Where the edge becomes too vague, this algorithm just outputs noise.

My next approach was a Canny edge detector, used with a Gaussian blur (with a larger horizontal than vertical kernel) beforehand.

```
norm = [cv2.normalize(img, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U) for img in cropped_frames]
blur = [cv2.GaussianBlur(img, args.blur_kernel_size, 0) for img in norm]
edges = [cv2.Canny(img, *args.canny_thresholds, args.sobel_kernel_size, L2gradient=True) for img in blur]
```

After tweaking the parameters (normalisation, blurring, and thresholding), this generally performs a lot better because it operates in 2D and thus takes into account horizontally neighbouring pixels. This is an example of a frame where the edge is detected just as I like:

[image: Canny, good]

The small parts of the upper edge that are also detected is not a big problem, I can simply take the bottom edge for every column.

However, in some cases, when the edge becomes too vague in some places, the Canny edge detector misses the edge there. For example:

[image: Canny, missed edge]

This is problematic for me. I would like to have an edge detected everywhere, horizontally, like my first algorithm does. In other words, I would ideally like to detect a single connected approximately horizontal edge, running through the full width of the image. That means:

- Only a single horizontal edge per image (so no more than one detected pixel per column)
- A detected edge for the full width of the image, so every column contains a detected pixel.

Is there another edge detection algorithm that is better for this problem? Or can I extend/modify the Canny-based approach I'm using now to satisfy my requirements?

If it matters, what I need in the end is the height (vertically) of the detected edge as a function of the horizontal distance.

Comment: It may be possible to think "energy minimization" method. (such as "Snake" )

Comment: You can try difference of Gaussians